# Using jQuery get CSS hover selector text-decoration value of an Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-selectors

Well,

I've minimal HTML like below.

```
<h2><a href="#">My Link 1</a></h2>
<h2><a href="#">My Link 2</a></h2>
```

CSS

```
h2 a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

h2 a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Using jQuery, I just want to find out `text-decoration` value of Hyperlink for `:hover` state from the existing css `:hover` definition (Means, Without triggering the event). Is it possible?

Comment: `:hover` is not selectable via js/jquery.

Comment: https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4434

Comment: @RayonDabre i think OP needs `$('h2 a:hover').css('prop')` which actually cannot be used.

Comment: I was thinking too much I guess @Jai :P So there is no way ?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tosoqiwiyu/edit?html,js,output